# ZF2 Advanced Routing: how to have user directories?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

With Zend Framework Routing (Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteStack), how can I add a module to support user profile pages.

But I'd also like to have it fall through to support other pages/modules from the root directory like `/rss` or `/search/asdf`.  This is my first guess with no luck...

```
'Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteStack' => array(
    'parameters' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'default' => array(
                'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/[:username[/:action]]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'username' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\UserController',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

URL examples ...

- https://github.com/weierophinney
- https://github.com/weierophinney/following

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Used Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Regex matching at the very end of the Route tree ...

```
                    'user' => array(
                        'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Regex',
                        'options' => array(
                            'regex' => '/(?<id>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)',
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
                                'action'     => 'user',
                            ),
                            'spec' => '/%id%',
                        ),
                    ),
                    'user-schedule' => array(
                        'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Regex',
                        'options' => array(
                            'regex' => '/(?<id>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/schedule',
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
                                'action'     => 'schedule',
                            ),
                            'spec' => '/%id%/schedule',
                        ),
                    ),
```